# C++ STL map , std::pair as the key

Tags: c++, stl

This is how I have defined by map.

```
std::map<std::pair<std::string,std::string>, int>  edMap;
```

I am confuse on how to insert values , I am getting compilation error always.
This is how I am trying to insert.

```
    std::pair<std::string,std::string> key;
    edMap.insert(key,d);
```

Compilation error is

```
1>------ Build started: Project: spellsuggest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>breathalyzer.cpp
1>d:\personal\spellsuggest\spellsuggest\breathalyzer.cpp(70) : error C2664: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::pair<std::string,std::string>,int,std::less<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::string,std::string>,int>>,false>,
1>            _Ty1=const std::pair<std::string,std::string>,
1>            _Ty2=int
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty1=std::string,
1>            _Ty2=std::string
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::pair<std::string,std::string>,int,std::less<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::string,std::string>,int>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>Build log was saved at "file://d:\personal\spellsuggest\spellsuggest\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>spellsuggest - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: For future reference, when you ask questions on Stack Overflow that mentions compiler errors, be sure to always include (i.e. copy-and-paste) the actual compiler error message verbatim into your post. We're human beings, not compilers.

Comment: Absolutely nothing to do with the question - but I'm intrigued at a file named "breathalyzer.cpp" inside a project(?) named "spellsuggest".

Comment: @Chowlett :) started with something and now with something. small goofup.

Comment: Whats wrong with: `edMap[key] = d;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's try:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> my_key_type;
typedef std::map<my_key_type, int>          my_map_type;

my_map_type m;

m.insert(my_map_type::value_type(my_key_type("A", "B"), 43));
```

Observe that the map's `value_type` is always `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`, so in your case it's `std::pair<my_key_type, int>` -- a pair whose first member is itself a pair!

With that in mind you can alternatively use `make_pair`:

```
m.insert(std::make_pair(my_key_type("C", "D"), -5));
```

Finally, as Sven points out, there may or may not be a comparison operator for pairs (I think there is, though); so if there isn't, you have to write one yourself. Lexicographic comparison on the two elements should do. Sophie awaits :-)

(Here's the lexicographic pair comparison; *you don't need to write this, it's already there*:)

```
template<typename S, typename T>
bool operator<(const std::pair<S, T> & a, const std::pair<S, T> & b)
{
   return (a.first < b.first) || (a.first == b.first && a.second < b.second);
}
```

Comment: There is one, I was mistaken; I've edited that bit out of my answer.

Comment: @Sven: Cheers, I'm just mentioning the comparison to give an idea then.

Comment: It's not valid to add an `operator<` to namespace std anyway. If you needed to, you could specialize `std::less`.

Comment: @Steve: Wait, why did I even put std in there -- I think it'd be completely unnecessary anyway. (But specializing `less` is of course even nicer.)

Answer (score 3):

The insert method takes a full pair of the map's type, so you have to do this:

```
edMap.insert(make_pair(key, d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this:

```
std::pair<std::string,std::string> key;
edMap.insert(make_pair(key,d));
```

will will fail to insert anything if there is already a key with the same value present.

This, on the other hand:

```
std::pair<std::string,std::string> key;
edMap[key] = d;
```

will either create a new item in the map, or overwrite the previous value, if one existed.