# How do I create an std::map with multiple indices?

Tags: c++

The following works:

```
std::map<std::string, Animal*> animalMap;

animalMap["KillerRabbit"] = new KillerRabit;
```

But what if I wanted to do this?

```
animalMap["KillerRabbit"]["White"] = new KillerRabit;
```

I have no idea what the 'official' name for the indices brackets are, knowing them would help immensely while Googling =p

Comment: They are called subscript operator, colloquially also known as array access or indexing operator.

Comment: Clarification request: Would you like to use "White" as a primary key to search for the KillerRabit object? Would you like the option to change the color from "White" to something else later in the program?

Comment: @ArunSaha
Yup, I want to find a white killerrabit while doing that, it's unlikely that I'll drench the killerrabbit in red paint or something, so I don't think so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a map of maps:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, Animal*>> animalMap;
```

Now each value stored in `animalMap` is itself a `std::map`. The key type for both the outer and inner maps are `std::string`.

The `[...]` syntax is the *subscript operator*. More specifically, though, you subscript a map with *keys*. Keys are mapped to values.

Comment: I will dedicate one rabbit named sftrabbit to you, now the question is how is should look!

Comment: Are you the "killer rabbit" in question? ;)

Comment: @Hobbyist Well my username comes from [this guy](http://www.bunspace.com/static/groups/160/logo.jpg) so that should give you an idea. ;)

Comment: @sftrabbit

That looks like a killerrabbit

Comment: Note that "fake" subscript operators are common for efficiencies sake, where you have one "real" subscript operator and a wrapper with fake ones.  The fake ones combine their values to feed it to the real one, which manages storage.  In this case, you could imagine the real operator being an `unordered_map` on `std::string`, and the fake ones building up a single key from the passed in substrings, maybe of the format `"[first_key][second_key]"`, in which you also escape (or ban) the use of `[` in your sub keys.  Similar to techniques for multidimensional arrays in one flat `std::vector`.

Comment: @Yakk
I thought about that but I'm using the strings for something else too, and I would have to write out a dozen string scanning code to break them up into two strings again, it seemed really hard with the string having no common denominator at all =s

Answer (score 1):

sftrabbit gives the canonical way to do it.  If you don't want multiple map look ups per key you could also use std::pair as a map key.

[Here is an example of doing it that way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371713/c-stl-map-stdpair-as-the-key)